# Setup IIS7.5 to only allow a specific AD group to see my test site

Tags: iis

I only want the group "testIT" to be able to view a test website that I have on my Server 2008 R2 server. What are the steps involved in pulling this off?
If it works, I need to do it on a dev site we have, followed by production asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set access permissions on the physical folder in Windows you can control who has access to the site. Simply grant the group access, and enforce windows authentication on the website, to ensure that anonymous access isn't granted, and that will only allow the group you specify access.